# Creating an AST Matcher using hasAnyArgument

Tags: clang, clang-tidy

I am trying to build a matcher which will find the usage of a forbidden enum value, e.g.

foo(enumDeprecated);
e.g.:

```
static internal::Matcher<Stmt> buildSimpleFunctionArgumentMatcher(
    const std::string argumentName,
    const std::string binding) {
    const auto hasArgumentName =
      hasAnyArgument(declRefExpr(to(varDecl(hasName(argumentName)))));

  const auto matcher = callExpr(hasArgumentName);

  return matcher;
}
```

But I add

```
Finder->addMatcher(
      buildSimpleArgumentMatcher(
          "enumDeprecated",
          "my_warning_message"),
      this);
```

Calling

```
foo(enumDeprecated)
```

Does not match.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

### Matching the use of an enumerator

The main issue with your attempt is the use of `varDecl`.
Instead, to match an enumerator, you must use `enumConstantDecl`.

In the Clang AST, a
[`VarDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html)
is a declaration of a stand-alone variable, like `int x;`.  (It is also
used for function parameters and a few other things; see the linked
document.)  In contrast, an
[`EnumConstantDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1EnumConstantDecl.html)
is a declaration of an enumerator, like the `A` in `enum E {A,B,C};`.
Their nearest common ancestor class is
[`ValueDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ValueDecl.html),
reflecting the fact that each evaluates to a value when used as an
(rvalue) expression, but that is the extent of their semantic
commonality.

As a demonstration, here is an example
[`clang-query`](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/static-analysis/writing-new/clang-query.html)
command to report all uses of a particular enumerator:

```
clang-query -c='m declRefExpr(to(enumConstantDecl(hasName("enumDeprecated"))))' test.cc --
```

Test input:

```
// test.cc
// Test clang-query finding a specific enumerator.

enum MyEnumeration {
  someEnumerator,
  enumDeprecated   // Goal is to report uses of this.
};

int someVariable;

void f(int);

void g()
{
  // These three are not reported.
  f(3);
  f(someVariable);
  f(someEnumerator);

  // This one is reported.
  f(enumDeprecated);
}

// EOF
```

When trying to match particular syntax, it is often useful to study the
Clang AST for that syntax carefully by running
`clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.cc`.  For the example above,
the key parts are the declaration of the enumerator:

```
| `-EnumConstantDecl 0x91fc430 <line:6:3> col:3 referenced enumDeprecated 'MyEnumeration'
```

and its use within a call expression:

```
    `-CallExpr 0x91fcb08 <line:21:3, col:19> 'void'
      |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x91fcaf0 <col:3> 'void (*)(int)' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
      | `-DeclRefExpr 0x91fcad0 <col:3> 'void (int)' lvalue Function 0x91fc628 'f' 'void (int)'
      `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x91fcb30 <col:5> 'int' <IntegralCast>
        `-DeclRefExpr 0x91fcab0 <col:5> 'MyEnumeration' EnumConstant 0x91fc430 'enumDeprecated' 'MyEnumeration'
```

Comparing that to the
[AST Matchers Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html),
we see that `varDecl` only matches `VarDecl`, and that matching
`EnumConstantDecl` can be done with `enumConstantDecl`.  (In this case,
the names arguably make that conclusion trivial, but in general, the
task of associating matcher to C++ class can be difficult.)

### Implicit casts and hasAnyArgument

From your post, it appears you want to find not just any use of the
enumerator in question, but specifically function calls where that
enumerator (by itself) is one of the arguments.  Using
`callExpr(hasAnyArgument(...))` is a sensible method, but there is a
catch.  Notice how the AST above includes an `ImplicitCastExpr` above
the `DeclRefExpr`.  That is because I declared the corresponding
function parameter as `int` rather than `MyEnumeration`.  The implicit
cast will cause `hasAnyArgument(declRefExpr(...))` to fail to match,
even though `hasArgument(0, declRefExpr(...))` *does* match (I'm not
sure why this inconsistency exists).

In the context of a `clang-query` invocation, one solution is to set
`IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource`:

```
clang-query \
  -c='set traversal IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource' \
  -c='m callExpr(hasAnyArgument(declRefExpr(to(enumConstantDecl(hasName("enumDeprecated"))))))' \
  test.cc --
```

That flag effectively suppresses AST nodes that represent implicit
conversions, and consqeuently `hasAnyArgument(declRefExpr(...))` works
despite the implicit cast.

Note that whether this is needed or not depends on how the callee is
declared, so it might not apply in your situation.

### IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource for a C++ matcher

You are using
[`LibASTMatchers`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html)
directly from C++, rather than calling the `clang-query` program.
Although I have not tested this myself, from reading the
[source code](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/clang-tools-extra/clang-query),
the equivalent of `set traversal IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource` is
to call `clang::ParentMapContext::setTraversalKind()`, which does not
have its own Doxygen documentation (and hence no stable URL) but is
referenced from
[`TraversalKindScope`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1TraversalKindScope.html),
and pass
[`TK_IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/namespaceclang.html#a6196a82dc53119822ac96e34a9726058)
as the argument.