# clang-tidy: Warn when a container holds a particular class

Tags: c++, clang-tidy, clang-ast-matchers

Using LLVM-15's clang-tidy linter, I'd like to enforce the use of a typedef. Instances of

```cpp
std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class>
```

used as a variable declaration, function return, or in a using/typedef, should instead be written as

```cpp
MyClassSet
```

where

```cpp
using MyClassSet = std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class>
```

I've tried, eg,

```
  const auto matcher =
      varDecl(allOf(
                  cxxRecordDecl(matchesName("std::unordered_set")),
                  classTemplateSpecializationDecl(hasTemplateArgument(
                      0,
                      templateArgument(refersToType(hasDeclaration(
                          cxxRecordDecl(matchesName("my::namespace1::Class")))))))))
          .bind("uset");
```

but this doesn't yield any matches and it's unclear to me whether it would actually avoid matching correct uses of the typedef.

Any help figuring out the right matcher would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

### Quick fix

The attempt in the question almost works for a subset of cases.  It
cannot match anything because `varDecl(allOf(cxxRecordDecl(...)))`
requires a matching entity to be both a
[`VarDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1VarDecl.html)
and
[`CXXRecordDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXRecordDecl.html),
which is not possible (they are distinct subclasses of `NamedDecl`).

The fix is to insert `hasType` before `allOf` to constrain the type of
the declared thing, rather than the declared thing itself.  With that
one change, the query now reports variable and parameter declarations,
but not return types or `typedef`/`using` aliases, and does not
whitelist the `MyClassSet` alias.

Handling those other cases requires slightly adjusting the details of
how the type is recognized, as shown below.

### Matcher satisfying the specification

Here is a
[`clang-query`](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/code-quality/static-analysis/writing-new/clang-query.html)
command that reports any variable, parameter, field, or
`typedef`/`using` alias where the type is
`std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class>`, so long as that type is
expressed as a template specialization, as opposed to using a particular
whitelisted `using` alias.  It is written as a shell script with two
preliminary variable assignments for improved readability:

```
# Common fragment for matching the specialization of interest.
typeMatcher='
  hasDeclaration(
    classTemplateSpecializationDecl(
      hasName("::std::unordered_set"),
      hasTemplateArgument(0,
        refersToType(
          hasDeclaration(
            cxxRecordDecl(
              hasName("::my::namespace1::Class")
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
'

# Query covering the syntactic cases of interest.
#
# In this query, the comments are ignored because clang-query (not the
# shell) recognizes and discards them.
query="m
  decl(
    anyOf(
      # Declarator declarations include variables and fields.
      declaratorDecl(
        anyOf(
          # Report when the variable (etc.) has the exact type.
          hasType(
            $typeMatcher
          ),

          # Also report references to that type.
          hasType(
            referenceType(
              pointee(
                $typeMatcher
              )
            )
          ),

          # And pointers to the type.
          hasType(
            pointerType(
              pointee(
                $typeMatcher
              )
            )
          )
        )
      ),

      # Look at function declarations to see return types.
      functionDecl(
        returns(
          $typeMatcher
        )
      ),

      # This matches both typedef and 'using A = B' aliases.
      typedefNameDecl(
        hasType(
          $typeMatcher
        ),

        # Whitelist the one allowed 'using' alias.
        unless(
          # These backslashes are shell escape syntax, not Clang AST
          # matcher syntax.
          hasName(\"MyClassSet\")
        )
      )
    )
  )"

# The 'IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource' flag suppresses reports that would
# otherwise arise from within the instantiated template.
clang-query \
  -c='set traversal IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource' \
  -c="$query" \
  test.cc --
```

Test case:

```
// test.cc
// Test clang-query finding the declaration of a variable that is a
// specialization (instantiation) of std::unordered_set with a
// particular class argument.

#include <unordered_set>               // std::unordered_set

namespace my {
  namespace namespace1 {
    // The class that should not be used with std::unordered_set, except
    // via a particular whitelisted 'using' alias.
    class Class {
    public:
      Class() {}
    };
  }
}

// Trivial specialization of std::hash to satisfy the requirements for
// std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class>.
template <>
struct std::hash<my::namespace1::Class> {
  std::size_t operator() (my::namespace1::Class const &obj) const noexcept
  {
    return 1;
  }
};


// ---- Things to report ----

// The goal is to report this variable declaration.
std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class> instanceToReport1;

// Also report when the namespace is not given explicitly.
using namespace my::namespace1;
std::unordered_set<Class> instanceToReport2;

// We presumably also want to report class fields.
class ClassWithField {
public:
  std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class> fieldToReport;
};

// Report parameters, including pointers and references.
void reportParameter1(std::unordered_set<Class> p);
void reportParameter2(std::unordered_set<Class> &rp);
void reportParameter3(std::unordered_set<Class> *pp);

// Report when used as function return type.
std::unordered_set<Class> reportReturnType(int);

// Report creating a 'typedef' or 'using' alias other than the
// whitelisted one.
typedef std::unordered_set<Class> UnallowedTypedefAlias;
using UnallowedUsingAlias = std::unordered_set<Class>;


// ---- Things to NOT report ----

// Not reported because it does not use the container.
my::namespace1::Class x;

// A different class that *is* ok to use with std::unordered_set
// directly.
class SomeOtherClass {
public:
  SomeOtherClass() {}
};

template <>
struct std::hash<SomeOtherClass> {
  std::size_t operator() (SomeOtherClass const &obj) const noexcept
  {
    return 1;
  }
};

// Not reported because the argument is not "my::namespace1::Class".
std::unordered_set<SomeOtherClass> someOtherInstance;

// Not reported because it is whitelisted.
using MyClassSet = std::unordered_set<my::namespace1::Class>;

// Not reported because it uses the typedef.
MyClassSet allowedInstance;

template <class T>
class SomeOtherContainer {};

// Not reported because this is a different container than
// std::unordered_set.
SomeOtherContainer<my::namespace1::Class> otherContainerInstance;


// EOF
```

I have tested the above with LLVM+Clang 14.0 on Linux and it correctly
reports all nine things in the first section and none in the second.

`declaratorDecl` matches
[`DeclaratorDecl`](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1DeclaratorDecl.html),
which is the declaration of anything that uses declarator syntax.
Most importantly here, it matches both `VarDecl` and `FieldDecl`,
whereas `varDecl` only matches `VarDecl`.  (I'm just assuming you
want to match fields too.)

In the AST matcher language, `allOf` is usually implicit, so I have
omitted it from my query, but it also works to have it explicitly.

I chose to use `hasName` rather than `matchesName` for greater
specificity, but either will work.

For ease of experimentation and reproducibility, my matcher is a
`clang-query` command.  Although I have not done so, it should be
straightforward to translate it to a C++
[LibASTMatchers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchers.html)
matcher.  I believe the effect of `IgnoreUnlessSpelledInSource` can
be achieved by calling `clang::ParentMapContext::setTraversalKind()`;
see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76107893/2659307) for
a little more detail about that.